# Vim alerts after a few seconds when no event occurred

Tags: vim, tmux

I use Vim in a tmux session, and recently I've noticed that Vim is raising an alert after a few seconds when I switch to another tmux window. Nothing has happened in Vim after I move windows - usually I do some edits and write the file with `:w` and then move in tmux. A few seconds later Vim alerts and tmux flashes that Vim needs attention.

Why is Vim being so needy? How can I prevent this?

#### Update #1

Output from `:au FocusLost` as requested:

```
:au FocusLost
--- Auto-Commands ---
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Links to `.vimrc` and `.tmux.conf`:

- [.vimrc](https://github.com/mafrosis/dotfiles/blob/master/vim/.vimrc)
- [.tmux.conf](https://github.com/mafrosis/dotfiles/blob/master/tmux/.tmux.conf)

#### Update #2

Using versions Vim 7.3 and tmux 1.6. This whole thing is happening when in an SSH session where tmux is running. I switch away from the Vim window using tmux keys `Ctrl+A` `Ctrl+N` as per the tmux conf.

Comment: This is Debian Linux, here's my rc files:
https://github.com/mafrosis/dotfiles/blob/master/vim/.vimrc
https://github.com/mafrosis/dotfiles/blob/master/tmux/.tmux.conf

Comment: What versions of tmux and vim are you using? Can you explain exactly how you're switching which causes the issue? I've got 2 tabs open in `gnome-terminal` each with a tmux and one has a vim in it, when I switch I don't see any issues while using your config files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `vim-gitgutter` plugin was causing the unexpected Vim alarms. The following line added to my `.vimrc` fixed it:

```
let g:gitgutter_realtime = 0
```

The following comment on the source gave me the solution:
https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter/issues/105#issuecomment-23055765

Thanks @slm for pointing in the right direction :)

Answer (score 2):

#### Auto Commands and Focus

Check to see if you have any Auto Commands (`:au` or `:autocmd`) associated with losing focus. These are the commands you can run in `vim`:

```
:autocmd FocusGained
--- Auto-Commands ---
fugitive_status  FocusGained
    *         call fugitive#reload_status()

:au FocusLost
--- Auto-Commands ---
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

The above is showing how you'd check this. The 1st example uses the fullname of the command, `:autocmd`. The 2nd shows the short form of the command, (`:au`). You can provide group names to either of these to show a subset of the list of Auto Commands.

#### Maybe you need Vitality?

I'm not that familiar with this but I did come across this plugin named: Vitality which looks to help smooth things out with `iTerm2` and `tmux`. It's not entirely clear to me what this fixes but it might be worth a look.

- [Vitality : Make Vim play nicely with iTerm 2 and tmux](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4014)

*excerpt from webpage*

> For example: it restores the FocusGained and FocusLost autocommands 
>   when running Vim in iTerm 2, even through tmux!

#### References

- [Vim documentation: autocmd - autocmd-list](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#autocmd-list)
- [Vim documentation: autocmd - FocusLost](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#FocusLost)

Comment: I don't seem able to put newlines in the comment - so here's another try:
http://pastebin.com/YjkwiYhA
- So it looks like there's no LostFocus event which is occurring

Comment: @mafro - add them to your question. It's OK to refine it as things develop. Just click the edit buttion.

Comment: @mafro - do me a favor and temporarily move your `.vimrc` file out of the way so we can just focus on `tmux`. Does the problem persist when you do this?

Comment: Removing `.vimrc` does indeed make the issue disappear

Comment: @mafro - good that's pretty huge progress. So we know it's a vim issue then. I'll keep digging.